# set next n values to zero when this value equal one

Tags: r

Given a 0/1 vector and a k value

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
k <- 3
```

I need to define a function f so that

```
f(x, k)
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

That is: if any value of x = 1 set the next k = 3 values of x to zero

I have solved the problem with this terrible solution

```
f <- function(x, k){
  
  .f <- function(x, i, k){
    
    s <- seq(i+1, i+k)
    if (x[[i]] == 1) x[s] <- 0
    x
  }
  
  n <- length(x)
  for ( i in seq(1, n-1)) {
    #for ( i in seq(1, n-k-1)) {
    x <- .f(x, i , k)
  }

  length(x) <- n
  x
}
```

Can anyone provide a more elegant (functional) solution ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: In `x`, as defined above, `x[3] == 1` so `x[4:6]` should result to `0`. But the 6th value in the result is `1`. Is that on purpose? Does this rule apply only to `1` that are not eliminated themselves in `f`?

Comment: Also: Are recursive functions allowed? "Pure" functional languages prefer recursion over loops but R has noch "tail call optimization (TCO)" so a pure functional solutions might not be best for large `x`.

Answer (score 4):

This takes some steps out:

```
foo <- function(x, k) {
  n <- length(x)
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] == 1) x[seq(i+1L, min(i+k, n))] <- 0
  }
  x
}

foo(x, k)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

This takes bigger steps when it encounters a `1`, should be more efficient at least for big `k`.

```
foo2 <- function(x, k) {
  n <- length(x)
  i <- 1L
  while (i < n) {
    if (x[i] == 1) {
      x[seq(i+1L, min(i+k, n))] <- 0
      i <- i+k
    } else {
      i <- i+1L
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But, if possible, I was looking for a functional  solution to the problem.
Something based on lapply or similar

Comment: @Andrea that's seems hard but if you don't accept right away someone *might* find a clever solution.

Comment: lapply is just a glorified for loop, you can translate this answer `foo2 <- function(x, k) {lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {if (x[i] == 1) x[seq(i+1L, min(i+3L, length(x)))] <<- 0}); x}`

Answer (score 4):

A simple counter will also do the job :

```
fnew <- function(x, k){
  counter <- 0L
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i] & !counter) { 
      counter <- k
      next
    }
    if (!!counter) {
      x[i] <- 0
      counter <- counter - 1L
    }
  }
  x
}

fnew(x,3)
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Advantage of a simple loop is that it can easily be converted to C++:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
NumericVector fcpp(NumericVector x, int k) {
  int n = x.size();
  int i;
  int counter = 0;
  NumericVector xout(n);
  xout = x;
  for (i = 0;i<n;i++){
    if ((x[i]==1) & (counter==0)) { 
      counter = k;
    } else
    if (counter > 0) {
      xout[i] = 0;
      counter += -1;
    }
  }
  return xout;
}')
```

I found interesting to compare performance of the different options proposed until now, which shows that a simple loop still has its word to say :

```
x <- rnorm(1e3)>0
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(x,3),gen_vec(x,3),foo(x,3),onePeriodic(x,3),fnew(x,3),fA5C1(x,3),fcpp(x,3))
Unit: microseconds
              expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq       max neval   cld
           f(x, 3) 7783.375 8205.9390 9340.76417 8559.7845 8868.092 33439.139   100     e
     gen_vec(x, 3) 2821.330 3086.5605 3683.71671 3176.2015 3490.867 25794.430   100    d 
         foo(x, 3) 1396.922 1495.1775 1689.60223 1532.5110 1640.818  5901.121   100   c  
 onePeriodic(x, 3)  879.178  994.0510 1090.42763 1049.4345 1103.793  2109.536   100  bc  
        fnew(x, 3)  413.538  452.7175  492.22530  473.6405  494.564  1142.563   100 ab   
       fA5C1(x, 3)  160.000  178.4620  274.42453  188.7180  213.949  7361.222   100 a    
        fcpp(x, 3)    6.154   16.4100   21.46069   20.5130   24.206    94.359   100 a
```

Comment: Nice one ... it could be of interest to know what happen when length(x) > 10^6

Comment: I tried with system.time(fnew(rnorm(1e7)>0,3)) : result in 6 seconds, vs 16 s for foo

Comment: and 9s  for system.time(fcpp(rnorm(1e8)>0,3))

Comment: `fnew` is a great improvement and `fcpp` is likely to be pretty hard to beat. (+1!). Do you mind adding [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62606372/1270695) to the benchmark? On my Chromebook, it runs faster than `fnew`.

Answer (score 3):

Waldi's `fcpp` function is great, but if you want to stick with base R, you can try this `for` loop.

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  l <- length(x)
  x <- as.integer(x)
  ind <- which(as.logical(x))
  for (i in seq_along(ind)) {
    if (x[ind[i]] == 1L) {
      x[ind[i] + seq.int(y)] <- 0L
    }
  }
  x[1:l]
}

f(x, 3)
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: This is a nice one! I included it in the speed comparison

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option:

```
onePeriodic <- function(x, k) {
    w <- which(x==1L)
    idx <- unlist(lapply(split(w, c(0L, cumsum(diff(w) > k+1L))), function(v) {
        seq(v[1L], v[length(v)], by=k+1L)
    }))
    replace(integer(length(x)), idx, 1L)
}

k <- 3
(x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
(o <- onePeriodic(x, k))
```

output:

```
 x: [1] 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
 o: [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are specifically looking for a functional programming solution, but, without claiming anything regarding the quality of the solution, this does the job:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)


gen_vec <- function(x,k){
  x2 <- x
  purrr::walk(1:length(x2), function(n,k){
    ifelse(x2[n]==1, x2[(n+1):min(n+k, length(x2))] <<- 0, x2[n])
  }, k=k)
  x2
}
```

**Output**

```
> gen_vec(x, 3)
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Original `x` is unmodified:

```
> x
 [1] 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Cool ... 
That is precisely what I was looking for 
No specif reason behind  functional programming. 
I just like it